# Why did this command delete everything?

Tags: unix, find

I run this command on a Unix box:

```
find . name CVS -exec rm -fr {} \;
```

I wanted to delete any file called `CVS` within any directory from the current directory and it deleted everything.

Fortunately all I had to do to recover was check out again from CVS. Imagine if I specified `/` as the starting directory!

I think the reason is that I used `name` instead of `-name`. I just rerun it as

```
find . -name CVS -exec rm -fr {} \;
```

And it seem to work fine. What exactly happens if `name` is used as opposed to `-name`?

Comment: This why you should always be extremely careful around commands that might overwrite or delete files. Here a handy way to test would be `find … -exec echo rm -fr {} \;`.

Comment: @Gilles Can you please explain the command you've proposed? Thank you.

Comment: @Eugene, the difference is the `echo` part, which just prints the command that would otherwise have been executed. The elipsis `…` are just Gilles' way to not repeat the other parameters in the example. So, the full version would be `find . name CVS -exec echo rm -fr {} \;`

Comment: @Arjan Thank you for your comment. I believe than under ellipsis you mean the underline "_", right?

Comment: Yes, @Eugene, these are actually [three little dots](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rWG6b.png)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing the dash before `-name`, hence it was looking for *paths* named `.`, `name` and `CVS`, where the dot references the current folder, hence deleting all.

> The find utility recursively descends the directory tree for each path listed.

You can easily test by using `echo` before the command you want to run:

```
find . name CVS -exec echo rm -fr {} \;
```

Comment: @ziggy, in case you missed my edit: so it was looking for *paths* named `name` and `CVS`.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. I have to be very carefull with this command. Thanks

Comment: Paths named `name` `CVS` and obviously `.`, which it found.